# How i can save image from @GtkCanvas()? Gtk.jl

Tags: julia, gtk

I am using Gtk.jl and want to save image from GtkCanvas
Here is my code:

```
canvas = @GtkCanvas()
draw_area = GtkWindow(canvas, "Canvas", 300, 300)
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Cairo to create a surface and then save it as an image.  eg in your draw function for the canvas in Gtk:

```
@guarded draw(can) do widget

    ...
    if _want_file_save_flag
        surface_buf = Gtk.cairo_surface_for(can)
        # Cairo.jl functions to write a surface to your image file go here
    end
end
```